# How to capture first 20 units

Tags: sql

(MS SQL)I am trying to write a query that would capture the first 20 loans originated from a new office. The loan numbers at my office are 9 digits long (100100001). The first 4 digits are an office identifier, the remaining 5 digits are a running total of loans originated. So if a loan file has a loan number of 100800015, this means it was originated from office 1008 and is the 15th file originated by that office.

Currently I have the below query:

```
SELECT    
    l.FundedDate,  
    l.LoanNumber,  
    l.BorrowerLastName,  
    l.LoanType  

FROM  
    Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE  
    l.FundedDate BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'  
    AND l.LoanType = 'FHA'
```

How would I adjust the above to be able to capture the first ‘20’ units from any office during a particular span of time (ie. month)? So the first 4 characters are going to very greaterly as it is different from office to office.

I do not want to have to adjust the first 4 digits (Branch ID) in the WHERE clause. I simply want to enter a date range, and if there are new loans (last 5 digits) i want it to capture those first 20 units.

Comment: Select Top 20, Order By Funded Date?

Comment: Are you not able to split out the office and load number into separate columns? combining two concepts into one column is a bad design idea, as demonstrated by the very fact that you need to ask this question here

Also, this really isn't a c# question.

Comment: Please modify the tags to include your database, rather than C#.

Comment: are people just guessing tags for their questions now? haha

Comment: Where Convert(Char(4),LoanNumber) = '1016' or some such (with Top 20), or limit 20 dependant on dbms would do it. Won't be quick though. Splitting loannumber into two columns as suggested by @slippyr4 woud be a good thing

Comment: (potential) problem with tony's solution is that it all falls apart if office numbers can have leading zeros. The solutions (in transact sql) to leading zero pad a number when converting to a string type are more clunky that a clunky thing. Back to what I said earlier.

Comment: Points to @slippyr4, I was assuming loannumber was a char type. If it's an int then either arithmetic or Replicate would be required.

Comment: sql is not good enough, was expecting dbms e.g. sql server

Comment: I apologize, but this is for MS SQL. So far this one is getting the closest:SELECT    TOP 20
          l.FundedDate,  
          l.LoanNumber,  
          l.BorrowerLastName,  
          l.LoanType  

FROM      Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE       l.LoanType = 'FHA'
AND       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),l.LoanNumber), 1, 4) = '5317' -- what i do not like about this one is that you have to adjust the branch ID in the "Where" clause. I do not want to have to adjust the first 4 digits (Branch ID) to obtain the new loans originated.

Comment: @user2888151 Without specifying the BranchID, how would you be able to get the results for a specific Branch?

Answer (score 0):

The query depends on the database engine you use but generally you'll use the substring function to determine the loan office, and to then include a where clause to match the office you're looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 20                                            -- only the first 20
       l.FundedDate,
       l.LoanNumber,
       l.BorrowerLastName,
       l.LoanType
 FROM
       Loan.LoanQA AS l

WHERE
       l.FundedDate BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'
   AND l.LoanType = 'FHA'
   AND SUBSTRING(l.LoanNumber, 1, 4) = '1001'               -- only office 1001
ORDER BY l.FundedDate
```

The above query would be for MS SQL Server.

If you're using a different db engine, you may have to use something else to limit the rows. For instance, for MySQL you'd use `LIMIT 1, 20`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the DBMS, this is the best I can help.

`SQL Server`:
If your DBMS is `SQL Server`, then you could do it this way by making use of `TOP`:

```
SELECT    TOP 20
          l.FundedDate,  
          l.LoanNumber,  
          l.BorrowerLastName,  
          l.LoanType  

FROM      Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE     l.FundedDate BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'  
AND       l.LoanType = 'FHA'
AND       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),l.LoanNumber), 1, 4) = '1234'
ORDER BY  l.FundedDate
```

`MySQL`:
If your DBMS is `MySQL`, then you could do it this way by making use of `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT    l.FundedDate,  
          l.LoanNumber,  
          l.BorrowerLastName,  
          l.LoanType  

FROM      Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE     l.FundedDate BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'  
AND       l.LoanType = 'FHA'
AND       SUBSTRING(Convert(l.LoanNumber, char(10)), 1, 4) = '1234'
ORDER BY  l.FundedDate
LIMIT     20
```

`Oracle`:

If your DBMS is `Oracle`, then you could do it this way by making use of `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT    l.FundedDate,  
          l.LoanNumber,  
          l.BorrowerLastName,  
          l.LoanType  

FROM      Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE     l.FundedDate BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'  
AND       l.LoanType = 'FHA'
AND       ROWNUM <= 20
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Unlikely, not one mention of the first four digits of loan number being the office id

Answer (score -1):

I was able to answer my own question, below is the query in MS SQL SMS. I'm sure someone out there is able to condence the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT      
    l.FundedDate,  
    l.LoanNumber,  
    l.BorrowerLastName,  
    l.LoanType

FROM  
    Loan.LoanQA AS l  

WHERE  
    l.FundedDate BETWEEN '1/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'  
    AND(l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00001'    
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00002'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00003'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00004'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00005'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00006'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00007'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00008'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00009'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00010'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00011'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00012'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00013'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00014'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00015'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00016'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00017'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00018'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00019'  
    OR l.LoanNumber LIKE '%00020')  

ORDER BY  
    l.BranchID
```

Comment: WHERE
 l.FundedDate BETWEEN '3/01/2014' AND '6/30/2014'
 AND SUBSTRING (l.LoanNumber, 5, 5) <21